# SSD for Mac Book Pro 2012 optical disc drive

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, ssd, optical-drive, sata

I'm about to upgrade my MBP mid 2012 with two SSD drives instead of the stock HDD and optical disc drive. I read on different forums that the optical drive link with the motherboard is only SATA 2 and that this will eventually cause problems with a SATA 3 SSD.

I, however,  see lots of videos and articles where the optical disc drive is substituted for an SSD. Are those new SSDs SATA 2 or is this not an actual issue (with the bandwidth)?

Can I use a SATA 3 SSD instead of the optical drive? Can I "switch down" a SATA 3 drive to SATA 2? Or do I need to find a SATA 2 SSD to use in the optical drive?

**Added**

I specifically want to instal two Samsung EVO 850 500 GB in my old MBP.

Comment: Not an exact science [hence not an answer] but every machine in the house has an SATAIII SSD on an SATAII interface. No probs in over 2 years.

Comment: @Tetsujin Good news, and are there oldish MBPs among them (mid 2012 like mine)?)

Comment: no laptops at all, actually. 2 Mac Pros, an 08 & a 10, the others are fairly generic PCs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SATA interfaces are backward compatible so you can use a SATA III drive on a SATA II/I port.

From the [SanDisk Knowledgebase](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8142/~/difference-between-sata-i%2C-sata-ii-and-sata-iii):

> SATA II specifications provide backward compatibility to function on
>   SATA I ports. SATA III specifications provide backward compatibility
>   to function on SATA I and SATA II ports. However, the maximum speed of
>   the drive will be slower due to the lower speed limitations of the
>   port.

I have actually done the upgrade you are describing (though with one SSD and a spinning drive in the optical bay).  There are no issues with SATA compatibility.

Comment: Actually, many SATA3 SSD have troubles with SATA1 devices. You need to check if the SSD is compatible or not.

Comment: @Allan Thanks Allan. Your sollution is actually the one that is suggested in articles where they warn about the SATA port for the optical bay not having enough capacity for a SSD SATA III. Did you ever try putting the SSD in the optical bay? In the [OCW Installation Video](https://eshop.macsales.com/installvideos/macbookpro_15_unibody_mid12_dd/): _The 2012 MacBook Pro's optical bay can not reliably support 6Gb/s SSDs and hard drives_. It continues _However, SATA 3Gb/s SSDs and hard drives will work without issues in the optical bay_. The HDD comming with the MBP it is said to be a SATA 3Gb/s.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - than those drives are not following SATA spec.  If it complies with the spec, then it's compatible.

Comment: @Mats - I actually put a 1TB SATA III drive (Western Digital) into the optical bay.

Comment: @Allan I know. And I was caught by surprise with this one, after buying an SSD (2 years ago) and tried to shove it in a computer with SATA1. The SSD wouldn't work. But it worked on another computers.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - I only ran into that issue once (but unrelated to Mac).  It was an Apacer SSD out of an HP Thin Client.  Since then, I stick to only well known SSD manufacturers like SanDisk, PNY, and Samsung.

Comment: @Allan My experience was with a Kingston V300 128GB. And yes, the SSD was fine and the motherboard supported that size of disk. In fact, I've installed a 1TB HDD in it and is working.

Comment: @Allan Cool thanks. I thought I'd simply try it out (like you apparently did) and you're giving me the guts to do so. I'll accept your answer.